# Creating Model in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am creating models in Entity Framework. I am trying to insert records in tblOffStrategy. In tblOffStrategy, OffId is Foreign Key and OffId and BonusStrategy are composite keys. DBA's creates table for us so I am creating model based on tables.

When I add-migration from Package Manager Console, I am getting "Unable to determine composite primary key ordering, Use the ColumnAttribute". Also I am not sure if my Foreign Key relationship is working.

Would anyone take a look at it and point me to right direction? Any help will be appreciated

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was able to do by overriding OnModelCreating method in  the class that inherits from DbContext class

modelBuilder.Entity<tblOffStrategy>().HasKey(t => new { t.OffId, t.BonusStrategy });

Comment: Please paste code instead of images. Also, why add migrations while you don't work code-first? And give more details as why you're *not sure if my Foreign Key relationship is working*